# How do i draw a filled square with a pattern in cpp

Tags: c++

I was given an assignment to make a program in cpp where you give it the width and length of the square and it will go into a pattern of *s and #s but I can't wrap my head around it. So I'm asking you people at stackoverflow to help me if you can. For reference when you would give an input of

```
6 6
```

the output would be:

```
######
#****#
#*##*#
#*##*#
#****#
######
```

and an input of

```
4 3
```

will give an output of:

```
####
#**#
####
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What have you tried so far? How far did you get? What is your code doing wrong and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Please notice that stack overflow is not for giving you a complete solution for your problem. You should at least do some trials and come back with a concrete problem in your code

Comment: ok so i know how to make the filled square but i dont have a clue on how to make the pattern

Answer (score 1):

This assignment is meant to help you understand how to use nested `for` loops.

```
    for (int i = 0; ...) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; ...) 
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Think about how a row can be formed by repeating a specific action. Then think about how a square can be formed by repeating the action of creating a row.

As for '*' vs '#', you always have access to both the x and y coordinate of the "current cell" you are about to print from inside the inner loop, because they are the counter variables for the two `for` loops. Remember: `i` and `j` are just arbitrary names. You could name those variables anything you want. You also have access to the length of each row and column, because they are given as input. Ask yourself: "what test can I make on the x or y coordinate that will tell me if it is the first or last column"?

Looping (or "iteration") is an **extremely important** concept in programming. Hopefully this gives you a hint in the right direction without giving too much away. :)

Comment: I recommend using variable names like *row* and *column*. :-)